# I can't find the vender.js when I use webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack and having a problem.I want to product a html in the public but I can't succeed.

when I use `npm run dev` ，I encounter a problem

[image]

this is my github

https://github.com/wohuifude123/webpack20180315

**supplement**

I have read you answer many times, and then I modidy webpack.dll.js

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + 'public/dist',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    library: '[name]_[chunkhash:8]'
},
```

and then I modify the webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
// 引入dev-server配置文件
let BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
// a third party
const manifest = require('./vender-manifest.json');
const _venderName = manifest.name.split('_');
const venderName = _venderName[0] + '.' + _venderName[1];

module.exports = merge(common, {

    output: { //打包路径
        //filename: '[name].bundle.js', //出口文件名
        // filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        // 可以使用__dirname变量获取当前模块文件所在目录的完整绝对路径
        path: __dirname + 'dist', //打包路径
        publicPath:'dist/', // 指定publicPath
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library: '[venderName].js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, "./public")], // 本地服务器 加载页面 所在的目录
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        compress: true,
        port: 6600,
        open: false // 将自动打开浏览器
    },
    plugins:[
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'server', // static/disabled
            analyzerHost: '127.0.0.1',
            analyzerPort: 9900,
            openAnalyzer: false
        })
    ]
});
```

finally I modify the webpack.common.js

```
plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], { // 清除 dist 文件中的内容
            exclude: [venderName + '.js'] // 排除 提取出的 第三方的 js
        }),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./vender-manifest.json') // 加载 manifest.json
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/index.html',
            //favicon: './src/favicon.ico',
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true // 是否开启 new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({
            assets: [venderName + '.js'],
            append: false // 不会被 webpack 自动打包
        }),
        // new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({
        //     assets: ['config/env-config.js'],
        //     append: false, // 不会被 webpack 自动打包
        //     hash: true
        // }),
        new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(), // 将[venderName + '.js']和['env-config.js']放进 index.html 中
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // 创建一个编译时可以配置的全局常量
            PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        })
    ]
```

Although I have read your answer carefully, I can't understand details.

I try to modify many places ,but the product can't work .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

**You are not matching the dll library to your app's output library:**

Your `webpack.dll.js`:

```
output: {
    // some properties
    library: '[name]_[chunkhash:8]'
}

//...

new webpack.DllPlugin({
    name: '[name]_[chunkhash:8]'
})
```

Your `webpack.dev.js`:

```
const manifest = require('./vender-manifest.json');

//...

module.exports = merge(common, {
    output: {
        // some properties
        library: manifest.name // this was missing
    }
}
```

What I see you were doing was matching the `DllPlugin` `name` to the dll output file library, which is not the case.

The [webpack dll plugin docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) inform to `Keep the name consistent with output.library`, but applying to where you are **using** the dll (while using `DllReferencePlugin`), not where you are **creating** them (`DllPlugin`).

**You are not creating the dll in the dist folder:**

Your webpack dll config looks like:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
}
```

which writes your dll file into `rootDir/dist` and not `rootDir/public/dist` as you rather wanted.

So the fix for this one would be to just change it to `path: __dirname + 'public/dist'`.

After those fixes your code started to work for me. If you have any more questions feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Hi sarneeh,it's great to see you.I have modified, but the production can't work, please help

Comment: Can you please explain output about webpack.dll.js and webpack.dev.js?I think the problem may product in these place.

Comment: @AbbottLiu In your `webpack.dev.js` `output.library` should be `manifest.name`

Comment: in the vender-manifest.json, `"name":"vender_5cbfa56c"`
if I use `library: manifest.name`, the case is invalid

Comment: so I use 



 const manifest = require('./vender-manifest.json');
 const _venderName = manifest.name.split('_');
 const venderName = _venderName[0] + '.' + _venderName[1];

Comment: hi,I have modifede the js, but  the case still can not work

Comment: I don't konw how to @, the sign is not working every time

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to help you more yesterday. Happy that your problem is solved! :)